# Should select inputs have labels?

Tags: forms, ux-integration

I'm currently redesigning a large form on our site and was wondering if it makes sense for select inputs to have their own respective labels in order to guide or smooth the UX?
What do you think?
Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[yes indeed](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html)**

> **Note 1:** Elements that use explicitly associated labels are:
>
> ```
> input type="text"
>
> input type="checkbox"
>
> input type="radio"
>
> input type="file"
>
> input type="password"
>
> textarea
>
> select
> ```
>
> **Note 2:** The label element is not used for the following because labels
>   for these elements are provided via the value attribute (for Submit
>   and Reset buttons), the alt attribute (for image buttons), or element
>   content itself (button).
>
> ```
> Submit and Reset buttons ( input type="submit" or input type="reset")
>
> Image buttons ( input type="image")
>
> Hidden input fields ( input type="hidden")
>
> Script buttons (button elements or <input type="button">)
> ```